# How to return correct error message to User when log in is restricted

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to ASP.Net web development and I am stuck in handling the exceptions when log in is restricted.
Question: I have owner log in and tenant log in. Now owner can restrict the log in for Tenant. But when the log in is restricted I want to show to the tenant that their credential is correct but log in is restricted.

Below is what I have tried till now.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LoginSubmit(LoginMV userData)
{
    if (userData != null)
    {
        UserMV authenticatedUser = AuthenticateTenant(userData.Username, userData.Password);
        if (authenticatedUser == null)
        { 
              ModelState.AddModelError("Invalid credentials"); 
        }
        else
        {
           //Do the login
        }
    }

    return View("Login", userData);
}
```

**User data from API**

```
private static UserMV AuthenticateTenant(string username, string password)
        {
            Res response = mdlAPI.AuthenticateTenant(username, password);
        try{
            response.Validate(username);
           }

        UserMV result = new UserMV()
            {
                DisplayName = response.objTenant.LastName + ", " + response.objTenant.FirstName
            };
            return result;
        }
```

`FYI` API Response is `response.ResultCode = Restricted`.

**Validate**

```
   public static void Validate(this Res response, string username)
            {
                if (response.ResultCode != Enumerations.AuthResultCode.Successful)
                {
                    string additionalDetails = "";
                    if (response.ResultCode == Enumerations.AuthResultCode.Restricted)
                    {
                        additionalDetails = "Login Restricted.";
                    }
                    throw new ValidationException(additionalDetails);
                }
            }
```

So in the above method `additionalDetails` get set to "Login Restrcited"
and the ValidationException is called. Also, since the exception is raised the UserMV object will not get created in the `AuthenticateTenant function`.

**ValidationException**

```
public class ValidationException : Exception
{
    public ValidationException(string message) : base (message)
    { }
}
```

After all of this the sequence of code returns to the Controller. As the userMV is NULL the error message that gets displayed is "Invalid credentials". Have I missed something.

I am getting the exception properly in ValidationException class. Do I need to do something else for the exception to be displayed to the user. I am a beginner so pardon my coding standards. Please guide me what else I need to do to display the 'additional detail` stuff to the tenant.

View File:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginSubmit", "Security", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "simLogin" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal-width-inherit">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReturnUrl)

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label ignoreSpacing col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { @class = "form-control" } )
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label ignoreSpacing col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control" } )
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Where are you catching the `ValidationException`?

Comment: I don't know how to catch that. Can you guide me a little. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Do I need to make changes in my cshtml to catch it. I am a beginner so can you kindly elaborate.

Comment: It looks then like the exception is not caught, so the API returns null. I'm not a fan of using exceptions to control program flow, why not return the `Enumerations.AuthResultCode` from the `Validate` method?

Comment: Exception is perfectly raised. I can see the message in `ValidationException function` to be "Restricted Login" but I dont know what else I need to do

Comment: API is not returning NULL. It is returning all the valid state with error code. I have got the correct error in the ValidateException function as "Restricted Login". But I dont know what further I need to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be relying on the `AuthenticateTenant()` to check the credentials for you and also to `return` the authentication result.

But, internally you're calling `Validate()` that in turn is throwing an exception. That exception is changing the control flow of the code. Currently, the only code that seems to catch it is either some error filter you have or it's propagated down to IIS and the generic HTTP 500 is being displayed.

I would suggest not to throw an exception as part of the `AuthenticateTenant()` method but rather return a `null` (or `false`, if you're willing to change the method signature).

Once you're back in control of the flow, you can rely on the returned result to rightfully call `ModelState.AddModelError()` with the proper message.

Comment: Since I am able to capture the exception. can you kindly guide me what code I need to add further to display the response to the user. If I follow what you are suggesting then what is the use of exception handling. I understood what you are saying. But I mean to say that I have correctly got the exception in my `ValidationException(string message) : base (message)`. Do I need to add some further handling to display it to the user.

Comment: @Unbreakable, Again, when an exception is thrown, it changes the control flow. If you want to retain control in your calling method after the exception is thrown, you'll have to `catch` it and call `AddModelError()` inside the `catch {}` clause.

Comment: pardon my ignorance as I am a beginner and still learning new stuffs. So I will write one function in the catch block. I will make the edit and will get back to you. So in the catch block I need to do something like `ModelState.AddModelError( )` right?

Comment: @Unbreakable, Something like `catch(Exception e) { ModelState.AddModelError(e.Message); }` make sense. Although, I would generally not consider a failed authentication an exception. And as a general rule, you should not rely on exception to return values from methods.

Comment: Ok, I will try the right way. Can you kindly give me a small snippet of `AuthenticateTenant()` and how to correctly handle it without the `Validate method`

Comment: Apart from "restrict log in" I have another scenarios too of failure from the api. Sometimes the error code is "Invalid Method". I need to handle this also. So, I need to differentiate between these in `AuthenticateTenant()` as per the response code received from API

Comment: @Unbreakable, Have your `AuthenticateTenant()` return `AuthenticateTenantResult` that will contain both the `UserMV` (when exist and valid, `null` otherwise) and the `ResultCode` (obtained from `response`) then use this data to construct the appropriate error message (in your controller).